# Why use explicit schema prefix in Postgres functions?

Tags: postgresql, function, schema

I am using Postgres for microservice backends and the databases are designed to be small(ish) and simple.

We have four schemas in our databases:

1. live: all the functions, tables, etc used by the application
2. utest:unit tests
3. testframe: unit testing functions/framework
4. testdata: functions that create common test data

When the database is shipped to production **ONLY** the 'live' schema is retained, all the testing schema's are dropped.

So my question is: Is there any reason for functions in the 'live' schema to  explicitly using the 'live.' schema prefix when referring to tables and calling other functions?

After much googling I am having a hard time making an argument for explicitly using the schema prefix.

Thanks, any comments are appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of `show search_path;`?

Comment: show search_path always returns "live" in production.

Answer (score 1):

Always qualifying objects with their schema names is a good way of making sure that no other objects with the same name in other schemas can be used by mistake. For example, the `pg_catalog` schema is always on your `search_path`, so system objects might be chosen.